# typescript Errors from `@aws-library/core` when running `amplify serve`

Tags: reactjs, typescript, aws-amplify, amplifyjs

When running `amplify serve` to locally test my React.js / Typescript application,
I get typescript errors from the amplify library.

Amplify and typescript Library versions (`package.json` snippet):

```json
{
  "dependencies": 
  {
    "@aws-amplify/core": "^5.1.12",
    "@aws-amplify/ui-react": "^4.6.0",
    "@aws-amplify/ui-react-storage": "^1.1.0",
    "aws-amplify": "^5.1.3",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3",
  }
}
```

`tsconfig.json` contents:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext" ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "plugins": [{ "name": "typescript-plugin-css-modules" }],
    "jsx": "react",
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "node_modules/*", "node_modules/**",
              "./node_modules", "./node_modules/*" ]
}
```

Some of the typescript errors I am getting from amplify code:

```
ERROR in node_modules/@aws-amplify/core/src/Hub.ts:82:34
TS7015: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.
    80 |                        this.patterns = [...this.patterns.filter(x => x !== pattern)];
    81 |                } else {
  > 82 |                        const holder = this.listeners[channel];
       |                                                      ^^^^^^^
    83 |                        if (!holder) {
    84 |                                logger.warn(`No listeners for ${channel}`);
    85 |                                return;
```

```
ERROR in node_modules/@aws-amplify/core/src/Logger/ConsoleLogger.ts:33:10

TS2564: Property '_config' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.
    31 |    level: LOG_TYPE | string;
    32 |    private _pluggables: LoggingProvider[];
  > 33 |    private _config: object;
       |            ^^^^^^^
    34 |
    35 |    /**
    36 |     * @constructor
```

```
ERROR in node_modules/@aws-amplify/core/src/Logger/ConsoleLogger.ts:80:4

TS2322: Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    78 |        let logger_level_name = this.level;
    79 |        if (ConsoleLogger.LOG_LEVEL) {
  > 80 |            logger_level_name = ConsoleLogger.LOG_LEVEL;
       |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    81 |        }
    82 |        if (typeof (<any>window) !== 'undefined' && (<any>window).LOG_LEVEL) {
    83 |            logger_level_name = (<any>window).LOG_LEVEL;
```

Why am I getting errors from Amplify, and how do I ignore, remove, or fix them?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get past the errors, but I am not happy with my answer.
I would *love* a better answer, that doesn't turn off these checks for my own code.

I was able to update typescript via `tsconfig.json` to suppress/not generate some of the errors across my entire project.
(Is there a way to do this for library code only?).

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    //other options omitted, for clarity
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false
  }
}
```